# Why does assiging a list element to a variable work in a different manner here?

Tags: python, arrays, list, variable-assignment

I have this piece of code:

```
lst = [[1,1], [2,1],[3,1]]
n = len(lst)
head = lst[n - 1]

head[0] += 1

lst.append(head)
del lst[0]

print(lst)
```

And I'm expecting this code to print: `[[2,1], [3,1], [4,1]]`
But it's printing: `[[2, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1]].`
I don't understand why. Please help me.

Comment: lists are mutable, what you have to do is `head = lst[n - 1].copy()` to make a copy of last ele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `head = lst[n - 1]`, that sets head to the last element of lst by reference. This means that the pair with values `[3,1]` is shared by both variables. If you want to not alter the pair in the original list, make sure that head copies the data.

```
head = lst[n - 1].copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for your need is

```py
inc_lst = [ [ x[0]+1 , x[1] ] for x in lst]
```

Hopefully it will help

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
head = lst[n - 1]
```

you got reference [3,1] as head, when you execute

```
head[0] += 1
```

you changed [[1,1], [2,1], [3,1]] to [[1,1],[2,1], [4,1]]

When you make append, lst got another copy of head.

Therefore, after del lst[0], you got the result [[2,1], [4,1], [4,1]]

Answer (score 2):

1. `lst = [[1,1], [2,1],[3,1]]`
2. `n = len(lst)` - `n` will be equal 3
3. `head = lst[n - 1]` => `head = lst[2]` => `head = [3, 1]`
4. `head[0] += 1` it change head, `head = [4, 1]`
5. `lst.append(head)` , remember `lst = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [4, 1]]` and `head = [4, 1]` => [[1, 1], [2, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1]]
6. `del lst[0]` => [[2, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1]]

Anyway, when head was `[3, 1]` then you change head and it automatically change `lst[n - 1]`

Also, please try using http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

A very useful tool if need to understand how code works step by step.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a very common problem among beginners in programming (such as myself). The other questions already answered the question, but I just wanted to mention that this is a case of "value semantics vs reference semantics". It can be usefull to shortly read up on this topic in order to avoid this kind of mistakes in the future.